# How can I extend test class in different bundle in OSGi

Tags: java, osgi

Now my project is working on OSGi.
I have a abstract class Parent in bundle A.
And Child1,Child2,Child3 is in other bundles.
As I have many functions in class Parent. So I write a PartentTest in bundle A.
But in other bundle can not see the ParentTest. So I can not reuse the code in Child1Test.... This means I can not know the  if the public functions is correct in Childs

What shall I do?

Comment: PLease put your code sa well what u have tried so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sharing the abstract Parent class in bundle A, you are no doubt exporting the package that it's in, and your child 1, 2 and 3 bundles are importing that package.

You need to do exactly the same for your `ParentTest`. It needs to be in a package that is exported, so `ChildTests` can import it.

In general, I would not put my test code in the same bundle as the normal code. Instead I would put them in a separate bundle that is only deployed for testing. Alternatively, you can unit test your classes outside of OSGi.

Answer (score 0):

The nicest way to do white-box unit testing of OSGi bundles is to use fragments, which will have access to all internal classes of a bundle, without being shipped in production.

In your scenario, it would be best to put `ParentTest` in a fragment of bundle A (either in a test package exported by the fragment, or in the same package as `Parent`). Then use fragments of the child bundles for each `ChildTest` (and have the fragment import the test package if you've chosen that style).

You may need to do an extra tweak to ensure the fragments can see the abstract class at compile time (it will all work fine at runtime). If you're using Eclipse, add the [`Eclipse-ExtensibleAPI` header](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fbundle_manifest.html) to the parent bundle.